# tab_style attribute not working in Salesforce Lightning mode

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have used tab_style in one of my visualforce pages and it is working fine in Salesforce Classic mode, but not working in Lightning mode.
What can be the reason.

Here is the code which I have written :

```
    <apex:page controller="MyController" tabStyle="MyTab__tab" sidebar="false" showHeader="true">
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C4EQAU), But now it's fixed in Winter'18 release. .

[tabStyle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_salesforce.htm) can be used with both page and pageBlock,

> Note:API Version should be >=41.0

Comment: Yeah, it was a known issue but has been fixed. But I couldn't get it right. Is there something I am missing in my code?

Comment: you also need to update the API version ( to latest one)  of your code

Comment: is your problem resolved

Comment: no, still facing the issue